# preg_replace with file_get_contents (link)

Tags: php, html, preg-replace, file-get-contents

I am using `preg_replace` with `file_get_contents`.   I want to create a `file_get_contents` with a page like (google is an example, not my actual site):

```
<?php
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://google.com');
echo $homepage;
?>
```

But there is one problem, If I search:

Not Found

The requested URL /search?ie=ISO-8859-1&hl=nl&source=hp&q=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2F&btnG=Google+zoeken&gbv=2
 was not found on this server.

I get the error, I understand it but can't fix it! Friends of mine tried too, but failed both! PHP have to set for every link "http://google.nl"

Found! thanks to Akam

```
<?php
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://google.com/search?ie=ISO-8859-        1&hl=nl&source=hp&q=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2F&btnG=Google+zoeken&gbv=2');
echo str_replace('action="/search"', 'action="http://google.com/search"', $homepage);
?>
```

Comment: How is this question related to `preg_replace`? And I understood that you try to load a remote site, what what do you want to do with later on? Can you post some more of your code?

Answer (score 0):

You need replace form action from `/search` to `http://google.com/search`

```
<?php
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://google.com/search?ie=ISO-8859-1&hl=nl&source=hp&q=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2F&btnG=Google+zoeken&gbv=2');
echo str_replace('action="/search"', 'action="http://google.com/search"', $homepage);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reaction btw!

Comment: @EvertArends use same idea